# How can I find function definitions in other files using Komodo?

Tags: komodo

I am using Komodo Edit 9.3 to write some Ruby files for a project I am working on. The problem I'm having is that some of the methods I'm using were written by other people and our documentation isn't quite up-to-date. I was wondering if there was an easy way to search for a function definition somewhere within a directory if you don't have the file where it is defined opened (because you don't know which file it is). I know that if you highlight the function and right-click there is an option to "Search for Definition", but that seems to only return results if the file in which the function is defined is already open.

Answer (score 0):

As you said, *Right click > Go To Definition* is the tool you're looking for.  You can also *Ctrl + Left Click* to get the same functionality assuming you have *Preferences > Editor > Smart Editing: Hyperlinks* Enabled.

Having the definition file open already is not a requirement of that functionality.  There are a number of things that may be delaying or breaking the functionality.  Your best bet is to try Komodo X though as we've update quite a bit around code intelligence which is what Go To Definition harnesses to find your function definitions.

If you don't want to upgrade you can try [resetting code intelligence](https://community.activestate.com/faq/codeintel-database-fix).  Note you have to wait for it to finish scanning your project after you restart before you get code completions or are able to use Go To Def.  In 9.3 you can see this in *View > Tabs & Sidebars > Notifications* and in Komodo X you can see this in the "Go to Anything field at the top of the window, it will tell you that Komodo is scanning your code.

If neither one of those things helps I recommend heading over to the Komodo forums to do some deeper digging.